# Mutating a HashMap concurrently in Scala without Actors

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-collections

What I want to do is to start out using some implementation of a `Map` and accumulate data into it by iterating over a parallel collection. Keys can "overlap" between threads as the keys are probabilistically generated (related to random number generation).

Ex. Thread 1 wants to add key = A value = 1 to the map. If it already exists, add 1 to the existing value (since value is 1) - if not, create the mapping. Meanwhile, another thread has key = A and value = 2, and wants to do the same thing.

Is there a way to do this without creating an entire `Actor` system?

`ConcurrentHashMap` from Java's library seems to look interesting, but the "weakly consistent" iterators are bothering me regarding safety of upating the map across threads..

Comment: There are other synchronization methods .. and it really comes down to what the desired results/semantics are.

Comment: wrt ConcurrentHashMap iterators, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768554/is-iterating-concurrenthashmap-values-thread-safe If these semantics are not "correct", what is? It is similar to choosing between READ COMMITTED, which allows non-repeatable (including phantom) reads, and SERIALIZABLE in a DB transaction .. which is "correct"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a very trivial thing to do without Actors.

```
class CountMap[K <: AnyRef](mapSize: Int = 16) extends ConcurrentHashMap[K, AtomicLong](mapSize) {
  def addCount(key: K): Long = (get(key) match { // Check value for key
    case null =>  // If not mapped yet
      val al = new AtomicLong(0) // Create a new memory slot to keep the count in that is thread safe
      putIfAbsent(key, al) match { // Try to put our memory slot in atomically
        case null => al // If we succeeded then our memory slot should be used
        case some => some // if there already was a memory slot, use that one
      }
    case some => some // If there already was a memory slot, use that one
    }).incrementAndGet() // increment and get the current value of the slot associated with the given key

  def getCount(key: K): Long = get(key) match { // get the memory slot associated with the key
    case null => 0L // if none, say it's 0
    case some => some.get() // if some get its value
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting - I assume I would just create an instance of this and use this to mutate values across threads?

Comment: I disagree that this is 'very trivial'. It requires detailed knowledge of the inner workings of ConcurrentHashMap. There are probably many more incorrect (bug-ridden) ways to extend such a class than there are correct ways.

Comment: Rick-777: It requires 0 detailed knowledge of the inner workings of CHM. All you need to know is that ConcurrentMap/AtomicLong exists and that you can read JavaDoc.