# Does Set of ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe in foreach?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, java.util.concurrent

Is it safe to perform foreach, add, remove, size operations in different threads with the next set?

```
private final Set<MyObject>  myConcurrentHashSet = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
```

I.e. I don't need to get maximum accuracy in foreach or size operations but I need to be sure that there will not be any exceptions while I am doing foreach / add / remove / size operations.

I know that ConcurrentHashMap is thread safe, but I am confused about the thread safety of its Set.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is iterating ConcurrentHashMap values thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768554/is-iterating-concurrenthashmap-values-thread-safe)

Comment: @Yogesh_D it is not a duplicate, He ask about the Set view over concurrentHashMap, which isn't documented well. The comment doc for newKeysSet() is very poor.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki "but I need to be sure that there will not be any exceptions while I am doing foreach / add / remove / size operations." because of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the keySet view is thread safe, the newKeySet in java >=8 is equivalent to this java 7 form:

for java <= 7

```
ConcurrentHashMap c = ...;
Set threadSafeSet = c.keySet();
```

for java >=8

```
Set threadSafeSet =  ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
```

Answer (score -2):

From [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) documentation:

> Retrieval operations (including get) generally do not block, so may
>   overlap with update operations (including put and remove). Retrievals
>   reflect the results of the most recently completed update operations
>   holding upon their onset. (More formally, an update operation for a
>   given key bears a happens-before relation with any (non-null)
>   retrieval for that key reporting the updated value.)
>   .
>   .
>
> Similarly,Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting
>   the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of
>   the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be
>   used by only one thread at a time.

Comment: If you voted to close the question as duplicate why do you answer it? Also you just repeat what I have already answered, and you just copy the documentation...