# Java concurrency - change mutable object after creation

Tags: java, multithreading

I've created an `Employee` Object in Thread A. An `Employee` class is mutable . In the same thread A, I've updated employee salary and change other fields. Then I put the object into a map and I do not access `Employee` object from Thread A anymore.

```
Employee empl = new Employee("Jhon", 12000);
empl.setSalary(9000);
Map<String, Employee> employees = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

And there is another Thread B, which constantly iterating over the map values in infinite loop and reading Employee salaries and other fields.

Is there any chances that Thread B will see the salary used when the object has been constructed (12000), not the updated one? (9000)

Please note, I do not update the same object from the different threads at the same time.

Comment: You are using `ConcurentHashMap` already so as long as you do not modify/read the object in Thread A after putting it - it should be fine. Also you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768554/is-iterating-concurrenthashmap-values-thread-safe) question.

Comment: When you put the object in the shared map ( I assume that you create this object in some method so it is a local object confined to this Thread) you publish it's state, so as long as you do not modify/read it after putting - there is nothing to worry about. If you wanted to modify it after putting it there - then you would have a problem and would have to synchronize on some common lock when accessing this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any chances that Thread B will see the salary used when the object has been constructed (12000), not the updated one? (9000)

Given:

1. `Employee employee = new Employee("John", 12000)` in thread A
2. `employee.setSalary(9000)` in thread A
3. `employees.put("someKey", employee)` in thread A
4. retrieving the employee from the `employees` map (map is a `ConcurrentMap`) in thread **B**
5. `employee.getSalary()` in thread **B**

thread B guaranteed to see only updated value (9000)

---

From [`ConcurrentMap`'s javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html):

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a ConcurrentMap as a key or value *happen-before* actions subsequent to the access or removal of that object from the ConcurrentMap in another thread.

There is a *happens-before* relation between `put`ting an `Employee` into a `ConcurrentMap` and its subsequent retrieval by `threadB`.

It implies that there is also *happens-before* relation between `setSalary` action by thread A and `getSalary` by thread B.

So thread B will see `9000`