# Java ConcurrentHashMap how to only add element if map size less than X

Tags: java, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

Is there a smarter way than ?

```
....
synchronized (myMap) {
            if (myMap.size() < 5) {
                myMap.putIfAbsent("something", true);
            }
        }
...
```

UPDATE:

After trying several things I think I might have come up with something better using an AtomicInteger dictating if we can add to the map

```
if (count.accumulateAndGet(1, (left, right) -> left >= 6 ? 6 : left + right ) <= 5) {
            myMap.putIfAbsent("something", true);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not only is there not a smart way to do that, but the way you've shown won't work either.  `synchronized` does not lock a ConcurrentHashMap, which uses an entirely different mechanism for its internal concurrency; you still have the race between the `size` call and `put`.

You might consider a caching library like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine), which might address your needs here.

Comment: A really good answer would explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand why there is a race between size and put ? The block is synchronized so thread are going to wait there no? Or are you saying the synchronized doesn't work on `ConcurrentMap` objects in general ?

Comment: `synchronized` will not protect from any other operations on the `ConcurrentMap` running at the same time.

Comment: Understood, so.. just by using core java, how can we avoid adding something to the map if the size > 5 ? It's not possible ?
Would `synchronized(myObject) {...}` work ? `myObject` simply being `Object myObject = new Object()}` ?
I have managed to reproduce the race condition synchronizing on `myMap` but not using a simple object

Comment: It's not actually possible to do this correctly and safely with a ConcurrentMap in the presence of other access or modification.  A Collections.synchronizedMap can do it, but will be slow as usual.

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to use the in-built `computeIfAbsent(Key, Function)` function and check for specific key being present and use the Function part of `computeIfAbsent()` to calculate value for key.

You can add condition to check for size of `ConcurrentHashMap`.

```
    int initialCapacity = 1;
    ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> a=new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    a.computeIfAbsent("b",x->{return a.size()<=initialCapacity?"800":null;});
    System.out.println(a);
```

For reference, check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/concurrenthashmap-computeifabsent-method-in-java-with-examples/)

Comment: use the .size the computeIfAbsent ? is that really thread safe?

Comment: Yes, .size might not completely solve the issue being thread unsafe, something like this might be used for iterating through the ConcurrentHashMap https://stackoverflow.com/a/3768661/21344674